# Storing primitive values in ObjectBox

Tags: java, android, objectbox

I am fetching orders from a backend that has two endpoints, one for fetching a limited number of orders and one for fetching simply the number of total orders available. I can store the orders using a CustomerOrder entity class but how can I store the primitive count value?

Since ObjectBox will not allow boxes of primitive types and requires using entity classes I had to wrap a single (!) Integer inside an entity class. Maybe there is a simpler way to do this?

What does not work but what I basically want to do:

```java
Box<Integer> countBox = boxStore.boxFor(Integer.class);
```

My current entity wrapper class (still only uses 1 row in the table):

```java
@Entity
public class CustomerOrderCount {

    @Id
    public Integer count;
}
```

I simply want to follow best practices and simplify things. Maybe there is an even easier method than using ObjectBox that is still legit that I am not seeing here.

Comment: ObjectBox is used to map entity classes to boxes. Other databases have similar data structures (e.g. tables or documents). If you only want to store a key + value, for Android possibly look at SharedPreferences or for Java at Properties as a better alternative.

Comment: I agree but is SharedPreferences the way to go? Is it bad practice to store a single value in a table? I read that you should be careful about using SharedPrefs.

Comment: It's not bad practice. I just suggested an easier way as asked for :)

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox Thank you! If you want, you can post this as an answer and I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this can go for `SharedPreferences`.

Or if you have too many primitive values to store you can go for [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb)

From the docs:

> LevelDB is a fast key-value storage library written at Google that provides an ordered mapping from string keys to string values.

The android bindings for LevelDB are available [here](https://github.com/hf/leveldb-android).

You can also use [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk). It's another simple key value storage for Android.